# ReactJS:Input on controlled component doesn't change state

Tags: reactjs, onchange, object-literal, controlled-component

I have an object literal with some empty values that I want to change according to a list of inputs. The problem is that, though the value of the input is updated with a predefined value in useEffect(), I can't change the input with the onChange handler. This is what I have:

```
const userValues = {
  username:'',
  city:'',
  country:'',
  description:''
}

function Comp(){
 const  [details, setDetails] = useState(userValues)

 useEffect(() => {
    setUserDetails()
  }, [details])

async function setUserDetails() {
      setDetails({...details,
      username: "username",
      country: "country",
      city: "city"
      })
}
const handleInputChange = (e) =>{
    const {name,value} = e.target
    setDetails({
      ...details,
      [name]:value
    })

   <Input fontSize="20px" w="sm" mr={5} fontWeight="bold" textAlign="center" 
               value={details.username} onChange={(e)=>handleInputChange(e)}/>
}
```

I have also tried to set the value directly in the onChange event

```
onChange={(e)=>setDetails({...details,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})}}
```

but the input won't change from the default value. Maybe someone can point me into the right direction. I followed this tutorial https://dev.to/deboragaleano/how-to-handle-multiple-inputs-in-react-55el Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the correct `name` attribute to you input element e.g.:

```
  return (
    <Input

      name="userName"
      value={details.username}

      fontSize="20px"
      w="sm"
      mr={5}
      fontWeight="bold"
      textAlign="center"
      onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
    />
  )
```

The second issue is the following effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setUserDetails()
  }, [details])
```

This code will reset `details` whenever `details` changes.
You will have to delete this effect or at least remove `details` from the dependency array e.g.:

```
const  [details, setDetails] = useState(() => {
  return {
      username: "username",
      country: "country",
      city: "city"
  };
});
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
    setUserDetails()
  }, [])
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! It worked like a charm. I have one question though. If I would like to set some predefined values for read only purposes, should I create another object literal that would hold those values and update it when  the values from the input object literal changes or there's a cleaner way to do it with only one? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. You can use predefined values inside the `useState` initialization

Comment: I'm using these values also for other elements that are read only like text. But for example if I want to reset these values from their predefined state to an empty string, the state will change across all elements of the component, not just the input fields.

Comment: move it to a new variable e.g. `predefinedValues` and make a copy in useState:
`const  [details, setDetails] = useState(() => ({...predefinedValues}))`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the info!

Comment: I've made the changes  but I don't understand where the userValues will go since through  the details property I'm actually updating the fields for the predefinedValues. Can you please give me a link where it explains how I can achieve this process?